# JQuery pagination -- clicking page numbers and removing href attr

Tags: jquery, pagination, hyperlink

```
page = 1;

$('.links').click(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    page = $(this).html();
});

<a href="#" class="links"> 1 </a>
<a href="#" class="links"> 2 </a>
<a href="#" class="links"> 3 </a>
```

when I click a page number, I want to remove the href attribute. The problem is, if I click pages consecutively, the previous page numbers clicked dont regain their href attribute. How could I do this?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JGpF9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the *best* solution, but still an alright one. This adds the href of '#' back onto the links before removing the current one. If the href's were different then you'd have to resolve this a different way.

http://jsfiddle.net/JGpF9/1/

```
$('.links').click(function() {
    $('.links').attr('href', '#');
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    page = $(this).html();
});​
```

NOTE: I would also add the spaces outside of the anchor tags

Comment: Ah, ok, very simple. I'm trying to think of how to affect just the one href which I'm re-adding the link attribute, instead of affecting all of them in my class. Performance might lag a bit if there's a good amount of links in the class. But this is a good solution otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
$('.links').click(function() {  
    $('.links').slice(page - 1, page).attr('href', '#');
    page = $(this).html();
    $('.links').slice(page - 1, page).removeAttr('href');
});
```